# Show that $\mathfrak {h}$ is maximal toral sualgebra iff $C_{\mathfrak {g}}(\mathfrak {h})=\mathfrak {h}$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak {g}$ be a finite dimensional complex **simple** Lie algebra.Show that

> Let $\mathfrak {h}$ be a sub algebra of $\mathfrak {g}$.Show that $\mathfrak {h}$ is [maximal toral sualgebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toral_Lie_algebra) iff $C_{\mathfrak {g}}(\mathfrak {h})=\mathfrak {h}$

I know that if $\mathfrak {g}$ is semisimple then $C_{\mathfrak {g}}(\mathfrak {h})=\mathfrak {h}$ hence the forward direction of the above problem is clear.I am stuck in proving the other direction.Please help

Comment: @DietrichBurde: No actually the result is mentioned here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1184280/how-to-show-that-set-of-diagonal-matrices-is-the-maximal-toral-subalgebra-of-sl

Answer (score 2):

If $L$ is a semisimple Lie algebra of characteristic zero, then maximal total subalgebras are precisely Cartan subalgebras, which are precisely abelian subalgebras $H$ with $N_L(H)=H$. For a proof, see Humphrey's book, page $80$ [here](https://books.google.at/books?id=TeMlBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA80&lpg=PA80&dq=H+is+a+maximal+toral+subalgebra+of+semisimple+Lie+algebra+L+if+it+is+self-normalizing&source=bl&ots=y-j1M1LvbN&sig=LiszhMdBUDG3cllk7XljyroX8eU&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjO6f20jJfPAhVLWBQKHfu5BHAQ6AEIJzAB#v=onepage&q=H%20is%20a%20maximal%20toral%20subalgebra%20of%20semisimple%20Lie%20algebra%20L%20if%20it%20is%20self-normalizing&f=false). Abelian Cartan subalgebras are also self-centralising, see
Theorem $8.2.1$ on page $29$ [here](http://people.brandeis.edu/~igusa/Math223aF11/Notes223a08.pdf).

Comment: Sorry..how does this imply that $\mathfrak {h}$ is maximal toral if $C_g(\mathfrak {h})=\mathfrak {h}$ ?Are you using the fact that $\mathfrak {g}$ is simple?

Comment: No, only the fact that $L$ is semisimple. But a simple Lie algebra is also semisimple.

Comment: But i dont see the relation between centralizer and normalizer?

Comment: The centraliser is inside the normaliser.